# Retrieving values from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My table in SQL Server has 3 fields

```
serial no. (int)
days       (varchar)
status     (bit)
```

With the help of a dictionary how can I retrieve days and status as a key-value pair from SQL Server using a `SqlDataReader`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems very much like homework, so here's some pseudocode to help you towards the answer:

1. Create a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to hold the values you retrieve.
2. Open a [database connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx).
3. Create a [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) that selects the relevant values out of the table
4. Create a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) using the SqlCommand created previously.
5. Iterate over the reader using its [.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method.

   1. Get the [Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlstring.aspx) field and [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlboolean.aspx) field and put them in the dictionary
   2. Repeat step 1 until .Read returns false
6. You're done!

I've put a large number of links to pages on msdn.microsoft.com into the steps I've detailed. By reading through those, and looking at the code samples that are present on each page, you should be able to put together some working code =)

Comment: ok..so in dictionary i have all the days and their corresponding status...in 1 form i have 2 datetimepickers..so now how can i get the weekdays between those two days and compare the days with the days in the dictionary

Comment: you need to map the values in the database to the **DayOfWeek** enum values and create your cleave.WeekDays object as list of that

Comment: @riya7887, that's an entirely different question, and I suggst you asking it as such, **after you've attempted to solve it yourself**.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<int, Dictinary<string,bool> dict=new Dictionary<int, Dictinary<string,bool>;
```